# Как в терминале линукс написать этот скрипт

Tags: bash

Написать скрипт который просит ввести число с клавиатуры в терминале на линукс и потом запихивает все нечетные числа от 0 до этого числа

Comment: Куда запихивает?

Answer (score 1):

примерно так это будет выглядеть.

```bsh
#Запрашиваем переменную у пользователя
read -p "Введите цифру: " ci
#считаем от 1 до значения переменной с шагом 2
seq 1 2 $ci
```

Если ввести например 10, то результатом будет

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

---

Либо воспользоваться циклом, к примеру

```bsh
read -p "Введите цифру: " ci
a=1
while [[ $(($a+1)) -lt $ci ]]; do
    a=$(($a+2))
    echo $a
done
```